# PencilKit clearing canvas not always working

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I am building a PencilKit app that interprets a canvasView.drawing's size. Drawings below a certain size are interpreted as tap gestures and get cleared in the interpretation process.

Effectively, I am doing it like this:

```
func canvasViewDrawingDidChange(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {

    // Check if drawing is empty,
    // otherwise this would loop

    guard !canvasView.drawing.bounds.isEmpty
    else {
        return
    }



    if canvasView.drawing.bounds.width < 10 &&
        canvasView.drawing.bounds.height < 10 
    {
        canvasView.drawing = PKDrawing()
        handleDetectedTapGesture()
    }
}
```

On my 2020 iPad Pro, this works flawlessly. On other iPads however, I observe a strange behaviour:

In a series of drawing little specks on the canvas that are all supposed to be cleared immediately, sometimes the canvas seems to not be cleared, a single speck stays visible. After I draw the next speck somewhere else, the clearing is functional again, which means the canvas was internally emptied, the visible state was just not up-to-date.

Finger input on the canvas is deactivated. The canvas tool is set to pencil, width 5.0.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Still happening with iOS 16.3 for me.